# ASP.NET AJAXNumeric Updown control in User control

Tags: asp.net, controls, numeric, updown

I have many (around 20 - 30) NumericUpDown controls, that i have added in to user control and they are associated with their appropriate textboxes. These NumericUpDown controls work fine and allow me to adjust the numbers in the textboxes. However, I need to be able to calculate a quantity if items as user changes text box value (withour post back) and need to set it on a label/textbox on the webpage. My problem is that I can't find an event or another way to do those calculations when either the NumericUpDown control is pressed or when the textbox value changes. I've tried:

- Using an event of the NumericUpDown control but it seems there are no events that fire when the value is changed
- Using the OnTextChanged event of the textbox control, but that will not fire it seems, even when I have the AutoPostback property set to true
- Calling a javascript function in the onchange event of the textbox control, but it seems that the onchange event is not called unless the textbox loses focus. The only way the user can change the value is through the NumericUpDown control and thus the textbox never has focus so this event is never fired.

Does anyone have any advice to get this to work? Just a note, I do have this contained in an update panel because I don't want a full page postback when a value in my NumericUpDown control is changed and the percentages are calculated.

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Via this: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_NumericUpDown.ashx

It has a currentChanged event that you can add an event handler for.  You can also add an event  handler on the textbox, using onblur (when it loses focus) or keypress (as the user types a key).  Both event handlers are necessary.

To add the event handler for the AJAX control toolkit control, you add the name of the method to the OnClientCurrentChanged property on the control, or similarly named.